# Does archive.org generate a torrent file for all file (download) pages?

Tags: archive.org

For instance [this game manual collection](https://archive.org/details/kirklands-manual-labor-sony-playstation-2-usa-4k-version) doesn't have any available on the page — I assumed that torrents are generated automatically by the Internet Archive for all uploads.

a screenshot from another page for reference:

[image: archive.org screenshot]

the aforementioned game manual page:

[image: archive.org screenshot-2§]

Comment: They are usually generated on file upload and regenerated when the files are changed.  Your url has a flag on it: ``this item is currently being modified/updated by the task: derive`` perhaps check back onece the updating is completed

Comment: @BlindSpots still not updated, no torrent available several months later...

Comment: I'll investigate further.

Comment: The automatically generated torrents are reportedly often missing files (recently [discussed on /r/datahoarder](https://teddit.net/r/DataHoarder/comments/12egcrq/ive_heard_people_are_archiving_the_internet/)). Personally I'll download directly in the future; see https://github.com/jjjake/internetarchive